# Sagemaker Pipelines - Unable to parse Pipeline Definition

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sagemaker

I'm using Sagemaker Pipelines to chain together two consecutive ProcessingJobs. I'm getting a weird error when I call `pipeline.upsert()`

```
botocore.exceptions.ClientError: An error occurred (ValidationException) when calling the CreatePipeline operation: Unable to parse pipeline definition. Property 'null' with value 'null' is not of expected type 'String'
```

This is what my pipeline looks like:

```py
    step_process_data = ProcessingStep(
        name='ProcessDataStep',
        processor=script_processor,
        code=os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "scripts/preprocess.py"),
        job_arguments=job_arguments
    )
    
    step_split_data = ProcessingStep(
        name='SplitDataStep',
        processor=script_processor,
        code=os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "scripts/split_data.py"),
        job_arguments=job_arguments,
        depends_on=[step_process_data]
    )
    
    pipeline = Pipeline(
        name="DataPreperationPipeline",
        steps=[step_process_data, step_split_data],
        sagemaker_session=sagemaker_session
    )
```

Any thoughts on what I am doing wrong or missing?

Comment: I think more snippet required, not able to infer anything. are you able to get definition?? import json
definition = json.loads(pipeline.definition())
print(definition)

Answer (score 5):

I ran into the same issue where my `job_arguments` were not all strings. I'd make sure all items in `job_arguments` are of the same type.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if you have all the objects are set up correctly can you please follow the below example and verify.

https://github.com/aws/amazon-sagemaker-examples/blob/main/sagemaker-pipelines/tabular/abalone_build_train_deploy/sagemaker-pipelines-preprocess-train-evaluate-batch-transform.ipynb